# onComplete method in Scala's Fututre monod

Tags: scala, future

I am learning `Future` in Scala and have the following code snippet. I am generating random marks based on the first letter in the name.
For the following scenario, I expect a list to be printed by the `onComplete` method. But it does not print anything.

```
def randomMark(name:String) = name(0) match {
  case 'R'|'A'|'J'|'S' => Thread.sleep(500); 99
  case  _              => Thread.sleep(500); 80
}

import scala.concurrent._
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val returns = Future sequence List( Future(randomMark("Rob")), Future(randomMark("Andy")), Future(randomMark("George")) )
    
Thread.sleep(550)

returns onComplete { e => { val y1 = e.getOrElse("Error"); println(y1) } }    
//This println statement does not execute. I expect a list List(99,99,80) to be printed
```

Can someone please help me to understand why the functional literal I supply for `onComplete` method does not execute?

Thanks!

Comment: If that's a whole program then it just exits without waiting for the future to complete.
Try adding ```Await.ready(returns, Duration.Inf)```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because you need to wait for the result because `onComplete` is an async operation.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent._

def randomMark(name:String) = name(0) match {
  case 'R'|'A'|'J'|'S' => Thread.sleep(500); 99
  case  _              => Thread.sleep(500); 80
}

import scala.concurrent._
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val returns = Future sequence List( Future(randomMark("Rob")), Future(randomMark("Andy")), Future(randomMark("George")) )
    
Thread.sleep(550)

returns onComplete { e => { val y1 = e.getOrElse("Error"); println(y1) } }   
println("Waiting futures to be completed")
Await.ready(returns, 5.seconds)
println("Futures to be completed")
```

Print's out:

```
Waiting futures to be completed
List(99, 99, 80)
Futures to be completed
```

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SWv18p8RTtuo7nMNHNHMoQ

Comment: Thanks Ivan! When I swapped the last two statements in my program I got the expected result printed. Thanks for for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Since callbacks are executed asynchronously, you'll need to wait for your callback to complete before the program exits. In this case, if you want to wait for an onComplete callback, you need to signal its completion somehow. In the following example I'm using a Promise:

```scala
def randomMark(name:String) = name(0) match {
  case 'R'|'A'|'J'|'S' => Thread.sleep(500); 99
  case  _              => Thread.sleep(500); 80
}

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val returns = Future sequence List( Future(randomMark("Rob")), Future(randomMark("Andy")), Future(randomMark("George")) )
val returns: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = Future(<not completed>)

val p = Promise[Unit]()

returns onComplete { e => { val y1 = e.getOrElse("Error"); println(y1); p.success(()) } }

Await.ready(p.future, 5.seconds)
```

But, you could, instead use `andThen` as follows:

```scala
def randomMark(name:String) = name(0) match {
  case 'R'|'A'|'J'|'S' => Thread.sleep(500); 99
  case  _              => Thread.sleep(500); 80
}

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val returns = 
  Future sequence List( Future(randomMark("Rob")), Future(randomMark("Andy")), Future(randomMark("George")) ) andThen
  { case e => { val y1 = e.getOrElse("Error"); println(y1) } }

Await.ready(returns, 5.seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Viktor! I did not realize that positions of the last two statements in my example. When I swapped their places, I got the result.